# jQuery Contains Longer Word

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
{
return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
.indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}
});
window.setInterval(function() {
$("div[class^='chat-box-content'] div[class^='message'] span:containsi(Dexter)").css("background","greenyellow");
},1000);
```

This is my current method of highlighting message that contain the word Dexter. However, sometimes in chat people say Dexterity, which also gets highlighted. I'm looking for a method to ONLY highlight appearances of the word "Dexter"

The message may contain other content. For example, here is a message:
Dexter: Actually, dexter

It contains the word Actually, which would not be matched by using the text function.

Comment: Are you asking to match part of a message? You can't use a selector to select words, only full elements.

Comment: What I have now works, it highlights each message containing Dexter. However quite often people send a message about Dexterity, which is also highlighted, however unwanted. I only want messages that have Dexter in them.

Comment: In that case you should get the element and check for specific text. updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want a strict match of text

```
span:containsi(Dexter)
```

should be

```
span:text(Dexter)
```

**Update:**

In that case you should use a filter..

```
var matchedElem= $("div[class^='chat-box-content'] div[class^='message'] span:containsi(Dexter)").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'Dexter';
}); 

matchedElem.css("background","greenyellow");
```

Comment: The message may contain other content. For example, here is a message:
Dexter: Actually, dexter

It contains the word Actually, which would not be matched.

Comment: This does not seem to work. It still only highlights messages containing the word Dexter, but if it contains anything else, it does not

Comment: Replace the comparison with a proper regex check and you're good to go.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with the code provided.